# Restfull webservice with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have created one restfull webservice:

(ex:`http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall`) I am trying to connect that restfull web service using AngularJS but I am getting status `0`  .

```
 $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall' }).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $window.alert('success')
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $window.alert('failure')
                });
```

This is my sample code I am getting failure alert but I need success.

Comment: my sample code is    $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall' }).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $window.alert('success')
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $window.alert('failuree')
                });

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console??

Comment: Any error on console? Any error on server side?

Comment: No guys i am not getting  any errors

Comment: Did you try to hit the URL directly from your browser? What does the service return?

Comment: [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: when i hit http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall server side restfull webservice i am getting result as                                        {"product":[{"id":"p01","name":"Name 1","price":"3000.0"},{"id":"p02","name":"Name 2","price":"4000.0"},{"id":"p03","name":"Name 3","price":"5000.0"},{"id":"p04","name":"Name 4","price":"6000.0"}]}

Comment: have you tried 'jsonp' instead of 'get'?

Comment: no i did not tried pls send me sample code of jsonp with restfull webservice

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to hit make this request from an application that isn't served by localhost:8080. If that's the case, you need to enable CORS on the REST service to be able to send request from a different origin. Look into your console. Look into the network panel of the browser dev tools.

Comment: just use 'JSONP' instead of 'GET' in your code. JSONP allows for cross origin requests.

Comment: @Tarun the web service doesn't return JSONP. How could that help?

Comment: Actually i have created on restfull webservie in eclipse and my appilication not in eclipse it is present in local drive and if i run index.html while communication data base i have used that code but not working

Comment: How to enable CORS on the REST service  any sample code pls send me

Comment: Please first confirm that this is the problem. What's the address in the address bar when trying to send this request using $http? If it's not http://localhost:8080/..., then why aren't you serving your pages from that server?

Comment: My server http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall and when i hit enter in browser i am getting    {"product":[{"id":"p01","name":"Name 1","price":"1000.0"},{"id":"p02","name":"Name 2","price":"2000.0"},{"id":"p03","name":"Name 3","price":"3000.0"},{"id":"p04","name":"Name 4","price":"4000.0"}]}

Comment: i am using the code  $http.get('http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall').success(function(response){
                $window.alert('success')
          
                 }).
                  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $window.alert('failure')
            });

Comment: @JB Nizet  if u have any solution send me code

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What is the URL in the address bar when using your angular application, and trying to execute the $http call. I'm not asking the URL of the web service.

Comment: file:///home/scriplogix14/Desktop/HiGi/kiosk/index.html#/welcome this is the path

Comment: in one js file i am using that code ie: $http.post('http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall').success(function(response){
                $window.alert('success')
          
                 }).
                  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $window.alert('failure')
            });

Comment: @JB Nizet if u send mail id i can forward  restfull web server code to u

Comment: You can't do any AJAX request if your application is served from the file system. You must put your HTML file and JS files on the HTTP server, and load the application from this web server.